# System Boot Problem - LUKS+kernel-4.13.3

Tags: linux, kernel, luks

I am facing booting problem after upgrading kernel to `4.13.3` on `CentOS 6` having `LUKS` encryption (`cryptsetup-luks-1.2.0-11.el6.x86_64`). I tried compiling the same kernel on another `CentOS6` which does not have `LUKS` volume, that works without any issue. But I am facing issue on the servers having `LUKS` volume. During booting, the system is asking encryption password and after that there is no progress. I have attached the screenshot. Kindly suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the `mod_crypt` and `mod_dm` modules were not included in `initramfs` while running `make`. The issue is resolved after creating `initramfs` with `mod_crypt` and `mod_dm` modules

```
# mkinitrd initramfs-4.13.3.img 4.13.3 --with=mod_crypt --with=mod_dm
```